# Accessing a file in Google Cloud Storage from a web browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to set up a file distribution to a couple of registered users. I am experimenting with GCS. The files must not be publicly available without logging in even temporarily.

I have created a bucket, given permissions to a specific google account, and done the same with the actual file in the bucket.  When I try to access

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/testfile.txt
```

I am promptly presented with a login page, and when I login with the proper credentials, I am redirected to 403 Forbidden page.

If I do not access the file directly but navigate to

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket
```

instead, I can see the file there in the bucket and when I click it, also download it by clicking it, which means permissions are correct (I have granted legacy bucket reader and legacy object reader).  But I seem also able to modify the bucket settings like storage (near/local/whatever), which in this case would be less than optimal.

How do I solve this? How can I make it so that by knowing the exact URL, a user can access it, log in with their credentials and then receive the file, without having access to the actual bucket and its settings? How can I make the direct link to work, just to include Google authentication in between?

Comment: The instructions to perform this are on this link [Making individual objects publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects) Please try those

Comment: Also check [Setting ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl) because given the 403 Forbidden error which is being returned, is obvious that [ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) is not granting the user permission for the requested operation.